# Decimal separator in C++

Tags: c++, decimalformat, decimal-point

I'm stuck with the following problem and hope that someone can help me out. I want to use a library where I can't access the sourcecode. (only *.h) In this library in a certain function an ASCII file is read.

- If I use this function in a plain main.cpp all works fine.

`Output: Test [-0.06 0.08 -0.02]*`

- If I link the lib in my big project(many external libs) and call the function

`Output: Test [-0 0 -0]`

I think that the decimal separator is changed in my big project.

Any Idea how to solve this if I can't access the source of the library?

I program on a Linux Ubuntu machine in C++ with g++4.8.1. It is a library of a old colleague (already contacted him for source but don't know if he still has the src) where I only have the static library files *.a and the *h files.

Example Code:

```
Mesh* vMesh = MeshLoader::load(file);
Vec3* toPrint  = vMesh->getVertex(4);
std::cout<<"Output: Test:"<<std::endl;
toPrint->print();
```

But this code actually tell nothing as i can't access the functions *.cpp code

Comment: We're going to need a lot more detail than that. What is the library? Completely hidden/proprietary? What about your calling code, how does that look? Do you know what language the library is written in? How it prints? Best I can do for now is point you at [`numpunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/numpunct).

Comment: What OS? If the library uses the Windows API and its conversion functions, the user's locale specifies the decimal separator. When parsing user input, this is a good thing. When parsing textual data, not so much. Most likely the library has a way to specify the locale. Otherwise you'll have to change your process's locale. The same applies to other OSs as well

Answer (score 1):

Well as I cant see the source I had to guess the used locale in the lib and switch back to my old locale afterwards. Not nice but..

```
std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "en_US"); //<-- guessed
...
std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE"); //<-- my standard
```

Thx @numpunct and @Panagiotis Kanavos